# Can't logically find critical points but everything works

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the critical points of:
$$ f(x,y) = (x^2 + 2y^2)e^{1-x^2-y^2} $$

I applied the product rule and chain rule for each of the partial derivatives to get these two:
$$f_x(x,y) = 2x(e^{1-x^2-y^2}) + (x^2 + 2y^2)(-2x)(e^{1-x^2-y^2})$$
$$f_y(x,y) = 4y(e^{1-x^2-y^2}) + (x^2 + 2y^2)(-2y)(e^{1-x^2-y^2})$$

When I set those two to zero I can reduce them to:
$$x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$$
$$x^2 + 2y^2 = 2$$

Which I'm pretty sure is right. Trying to solve those two I only get nonsense like
$1 = 2$ or the square root of a negative. I looked at the answer and the points are
$(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1), (0,0)$

I can see that those work out with the two formulas right above but I can't get there logically. Is there a flaw in my reasoning so far or do I just need to keep working to solve those two partials ? Also if $y$ is undefined for a value of x does that make it critical value of $x$ ?

Comment: Why did you drop $x=y=0?$

Comment: "$y$ is undefined for a value of $x$" doesn't make sense. You mean that for a value of $x$, there are no values of $y$ where $(x,y)$ is a critical point?

Comment: One way you could check your work is to test one of the answer's critical points and see what happens.  For example, $(0,0)$ is a critical point according to your initial $f_x$ and $f_y$, but not according to your reduced equations.  So then you know that something went wrong when you took that step.

Comment: Thanks I left (0,0) out because I thought of it as a gimmie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost some parts when you reduced your equations. They should read
\begin{align*}
2x(1-x^2-2y^2)e^{1-x^2-y^2} &= 0,\\
2y(2-x^2-2y^2)e^{1-x^2-y^2} &= 0.
\end{align*}
Sure, the exponential does not matter, but this system of equations has more solutions than yours, e.g., $x = 0$ solves the first equation and then you can solve for $y$ in the second one. You also get the solution $(0,0)$, which apparently the answer also missed.

Comment: How is this different than what I have above ? What I have is just a manipulation of (1−^2−2^2). If either expression in parentheses goes to zero then the whole thing becomes zero that's why I was solving for it individually. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, but you missed that $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ also cause the equations to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

You cancelled out $x$ in the first equation and $y$ in the second. That leaves with the possibility of $x=0$ and $y=0$ providing critical points. In fact, $x=y=0$ gives the absolute minimum of $f$. Note that $x=0, x^{2}+2y^{2}=2$ and $y=0, x^{2}+2y^{2}=1$ also have solutions.

Answer (score 2):

After eliminating the exponential factor (which is never zero), the system to solve should be
$$\begin{cases}
x(x^2 + 2y^2 - 1)=0\\
y(x^2 + 2y^2 - 2)=0
\end{cases}$$
From the first one we get
$$\begin{cases}
x=0\\
y(x^2 + 2y^2 - 2)=0
\end{cases}
\cup
\begin{cases}
x^2 + 2y^2=1\\
y(x^2 + 2y^2 - 2)=0
\end{cases}
$$
that is
$$\begin{cases}
x=0\\
y(y^2 - 1)=0
\end{cases}
\cup
\begin{cases}
x^2 + 2y^2=1\\
y=0
\end{cases}$$
or
$$\begin{cases}
x=0\\
y(y-1)(y+1)=0
\end{cases}
\cup
\begin{cases}
(x-1)(x+1)=0\\
y=0
\end{cases}$$
Therefore the critical points are $(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)$ AND $(0,0)$ (which is a global minimum point since $f(0,0)=0$ and $f\geq 0$).

Comment: A little above my head thank you though